# How to get a list of key values from array of JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Lets say, I have an array of objects like this:

```
var students = [{
    name: 'Nick',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
}, {
    name: 'Jordan',
    achievements: '175',
    points: '16375'
}, {
    name: 'Ramon',
    achievements: '55',
    points: '2025'
}];
```

How do I loop through it (if i have to) so I get a list of certain key values.
Lets say a list of all names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can take `Array.map()`. This method returns an array with the elements from the callback returned. It expect that all elements return something. If not set, `undefined` will be returned.

```js
var students = [{
    name: 'Nick',
    achievements: 158,
    points: 14730
}, {
    name: 'Jordan',
    achievements: '175',
    points: '16375'
}, {
    name: 'Ramon',
    achievements: '55',
    points: '2025'
}];
var nameArray = students.map(function (el) { return el.name; });
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(nameArray, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `forEach`:

```
var a = [];
students.forEach(function(obj){
    a.push(obj.name);
})
console.log(a);
```

Output:

```
 ["Nick", "Jordan", "Ramon"]
```